# Error DNS al abrir web desde dispositivo movil

Tags: javascript, html, css

Desde hace 2 días no me deja abrir mi pagina web en dispositivo móvil me sale este error: [image: Error al intentar abrir pagina desde dispositivo]

me he puesto en contacto con soporte técnico de Hostinger y me han dicho que es un error de código pero he subido una pagina nueva con pocas lineas de codigo y sigue saliendo el mismo error, me han mandado aquí para buscar ayuda.. gracias Web: https://www.mallorcamarexcursiones.es

Comment: Es más fácil buscar el error directamente en san google y te llevará a resultados como [este artículo](https://kinsta.com/es/base-de-conocimiento/dns_probe_finished_nxdomain/) que espero pueda servirte.

Comment: ¿Dices que no funciona desde el movil, porque SI funciona desde una PC? Lo dudo, por tanto, el movil nada tiene que ver con esto, así como las etiquetas que has puesto, ninguna viene al caso.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!